# sql calculate date from today and duration

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table named subscribers
and it have

- users <<===== memebers
- status <<===== for active or disable 0 or 1
- date <<===== started date ex: 2013-12-06
- duration <<=====  here i set like 30 days

so what im trying to do here is calculate from started date and current date and duration

and set status to 0 if the 30 days from duration is expired

here is the code

```
mysql_query("UPDATE subscribers SET status=1, WHERE status = 0 and (TO_DAYS(date) + duration) - TO_DAYS(NOW())  < 0");
```

sorry for my english and thank you for your help

Comment: mysql_query("UPDATE subscribers SET status=1 WHERE status = 0 and (TO_DAYS(date) + duration) - TO_DAYS(NOW())  < 0");

Comment: you just hav to remove the `,` intruder before WHERE

Comment: @Melon, Please add this comment in the answer. Snoobih, If the field is always updated please consider not using the field, only the SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Your schema and your approach are ok

You just have a syntax error: remove the `,` intruder before `WHERE`

also as **Vinicius Monteiro** says :

> If the field is always updated please consider not using the field, only the SELECT

so your query should look like:

```
UPDATE subscribers SET status=0 WHERE (TO_DAYS(date) + duration) - TO_DAYS(NOW())  < 0
```

also if you have: `sql_safe_updates=1` the previous update will throw you an error. 
If that is the case search in Google for: "MySQL disable safe update"

Comment: But it will set status to 1 not 0 as asked in question.